# CLI Markdown viewer with Chapter selection support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, markdown, command-line

I'm looking for a simple CLI Markdown viewer with support for Chapter selection for *Ubuntu*. My main goal is to have a single file with notes separated to chapters so I can list those and select one to view that only one.

Markdown is only suppose to help with the readability and add some colors to the output; however, it might not be the best option for me, so I'm open to other ideas.

**These are the ones I've tried already:**

- mdless
- mdp
- mad(1)
- mdr
- mdv

But none of these support what I'm looking for.

My formatting would look something like this:

```
### Chapter 1
Chap content

### Chapter 2
Chap content
```

I've tough about doing this in Python so I could just grep everything starting with "###" then somehow printing everything til the next triple-hash, but I'm not quite sure how to combine this with syntax highlighting and scalability.

Do someone know a way to make this work somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I find `glow` to be pretty nice and featureful cli markdown reader that supports Chapter. Source and installation instructions for many different distributions available on [github](https://github.com/charmbracelet/glow).

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://repo.charm.sh/apt/gpg.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/charm.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/charm.gpg] https://repo.charm.sh/apt/ * *" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/charm.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install glow
```